# Navbar not collapsing soon enough - cutting off right-most item

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I have a navbar menu in Bootstrap 4.  When I resize the page, it resizes after a certain size threshold, but before it collapses, the far-right item "Opportunities" in the navbar is being cutoff.

In other words, it's cutting off items - it eventually collapses if the window gets too small - but before that, it's cutting off.  See photo here:

[image]

Is there an easy fix here?  Code below..

```css
/* ------------------------------Navigation------------------------------*/

/*  Navigation pills */

#navPills li{
  padding:6px 6px 6px 6px !important;
  font-size: 14px !important;
}

#nav-pills ul{

  
}

/*  Navigation pills text*/
.btn.btn-s-md.btn-white.m-b {
  font-size: 14px !important;
  letter-spacing: .04em;
}

.navbar {
  background-color:#f7f7f7 !important;    
  padding-bottom:10px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #E6E7E8;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(159,159,155,0.4)
}


#toggle {
    background-color:none;
    color:black;
}

.nav-item {
  text-align: right;
  padding:0px 10px 0px 10px
}

.nav-link {
  text-align:left;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#0c2d1c !important;    
}

#navbarNav {

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/css/bootstrap4-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<body>
<!-- Navigation -->
  <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark sticky-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <div class="logo_subheader">
        Land Use and Environment Lab
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="logo_header">
        GLUE
        <br>
      </div>
    </a>
    <button id="toggle" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-left" id="navbarNav">
      <ul id = "navPills" class=" nav-pills navbar-nav ml-auto">    
        <li>
          <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-s-md btn-white m-b active">ABOUT
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="people.html" class="btn btn-s-md btn-white m-b">
            PEOPLE
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="research.html" class="btn btn-s-md btn-white m-b">RESEARCH
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="publications.html" class="btn btn-s-md btn-white m-b">PUBLICATIONS
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="media.html" class="btn btn-s-md btn-white m-b">
          MEDIA
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="teaching.html" class="btn btn-s-md btn-white m-b">
          TEACHING
          </a>
        </li>       
        <li>
           <a href="opportunities.html" class="btn btn-s-md btn-white m-b">
          OPPORTUNITIES
          </a>
        </li>     
      </ul> 
    </div>
  </nav>
  
</body>


 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/js/bootstrap4-toggle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Change `navbar-expand-lg` to `navbar-expand-xl` and that should do the trick. [Bootstrap 4 Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navbar)

Comment: It now collapses a bit early, but that did the trick!

Comment: The problem is that you only have 5 different options available^^ xl is the highest one so be careful how long your menu entries are. Consider joining a few together into a dropdown menu and using a smaller expand value.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Bootstrap 4 docs for Navbar example (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/), I would erase your li classes as they seem to cause the overlap with the edge of the viewport to happen.

If you put these classes on your ul element you will have the same lg collapse and styling of buttons. See code below for the changes I am referring to.

```
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark sticky-top">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
  <div class="logo_subheader">
    Land Use and Environment Lab
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="logo_header">
    GLUE
    <br>
  </div>
</a>
<button id="toggle" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-left" id="navbarNav">
  <ul id="navPills" class=" nav-pills navbar-nav ml-auto btn btn-s-md btn-white m-b">    
    <li>
      <a href="index.html">ABOUT
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="people.html">
        PEOPLE
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="research.html">RESEARCH
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="publications.html">PUBLICATIONS
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a href="media.html">
      MEDIA
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a href="teaching.html">
      TEACHING
      </a>
    </li>       
    <li>
       <a href="opportunities.html">
      OPPORTUNITIES
      </a>
    </li>     
  </ul> 
</div>
```